# Check if view model property has value in Javascript using MVC Razor syntax

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I get value from view model in Javascript if the property is nullable like `int?`, `bool?` etc. 
I easily managed to check if property has a value, it works until I return it's value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Works as expected
    var year = !!'@Model.Year' ? 1994 : 0;

    // Null reference exceptin thrown
    var year2 = !!'@Model.Year' ? @Model.Year.Value : 0;

</script>
```

For some reason the condition is ignored when returning property using razor syntax. The same happens if use `if` and `else` statements.


**Edit:**
The exception is thrown also if using `@Model.Year.HasValue.ToString().ToLower()` to check for null value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `HasValue` property on the nullable int variable to determine whether it has value or not, If yes, read the value, else set the default value you want. You can do this in one c# statement so that you do not need to worry about `True` and `true` inconsistencies between C# and javascript.

This should work fine.

```
<script>

    var year = @(Model.Year.HasValue ? Model.Year.Value : 0);
    alert(year);

</script>
```

Here we wrapped the entire expression as a single C# statement by wrapping it in `@(` and `)`. So when this page is loaded, razor will run the C# statement and set the resulting value to your javascript variable.

Comment: Found a way how to write in multiple lines. For Javascript just need to use `@:` like this: `var someVar = 0;@if(Model.Year.HasValue){@:someVar = '@Model.Year.Value';}else if(Model.Year2.HasValue){ @:someVar = '@Model.Year2.Value';}`

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use this:

```
var year = @(@Model.Year??0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Model.Year.HasValue` to check for nulls.

```
var year2 = @Model.Year.HasValue ? @Model.Year.Value : 0;
```

Comment: This will not work as in c# boolean value is `True` or `False` whereas in Javascript `true` or `false`. It would work if you put `@Model.Year.HasValue.ToString().ToLower()` @Kartik Jethani.